# Multiple UILabel instances

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm creating multiple instances of a UILabel to display on a map that will have many labels and allow the user to return an id or tag number of the selected one. The code below only returns the last instance created, likely due to the same variable "newCity".

The two instances will have data filled in dynamically from a pList which I will loop through to get the city, idNumber, and x & y placement of the label. The count of cities will be different each time, and may even change dynamically. Two are shown for clarity.

The question is how to get the correct idNumber for the right label being tapped? 
I've searched many places but found no solutions that work without causing other problems. How do I create new instances and still get the correct one?

Also notice the tapGestureRecognizer below has tapGesture and tapGesture2 names. It doesn't work with the same one.  How can I use a tapGesture with one name and recognize which label?

I'd rather use labels than buttons unless there is no other way.  I may even add a touchesBegan or touchesMoved to adjust the subView that I don't want to conflict with the tapGesture in the label.

I appreciate your help.

WBCitiesView.h

```
@interface WBCitiesView : UIViewController 
{
    UIView      *subView;
    int         resultNumber;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIView *subView;
@property int resultNumber;

- (void) touchUp:(id)sender;

@end
```

WBCitiesView.m

```
#import "WBCitiesView.h"
#import "WBCities.h"


@interface WBCitiesView ()

@end

@implementation WBCitiesView

@synthesize subView, resultNumber;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}


WBCities *newCity;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect mapFrame = CGRectMake(20, 30, 250, 300);
    subView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:mapFrame];
    subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    subView.alpha = .5;
    subView.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:subView action:@selector(swipe:)];///was self
    [subView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
    [self.view addSubview:subView];




    newCity =[[WBCities alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 20, 100, 30)];
    newCity.city = @"CityA";
    newCity.idNumber = 1111;
    newCity.size = 0;
    [newCity setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [newCity setText:newCity.city];
    [newCity setTag:newCity.idNumber];
    newCity.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:)];
    [newCity addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [subView addSubview:newCity];


    newCity =[[WBCities alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 70, 100, 30)];
    newCity.city = @"CityB";
    newCity.idNumber = 2222;
    newCity.size = 1;
    [newCity setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [newCity setText:newCity.city];
    [newCity setTag:newCity.idNumber];
    newCity.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:)];
    [newCity addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture2];
    [subView addSubview:newCity];



-(void) touchUp:(id)sender
{

    resultNumber = [newCity returnIdNumber];
}
```

WBCities.h

```
@interface WBCities : UILabel{
    NSString    *city;
    int         idNumber;
    BOOL        size;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *city;
@property (nonatomic) int idNumber;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL size;

-(int)returnIdNumber;

@end
```

WBCities.m

```
#import "WBCities.h"
#import "WBCitiesView.h"

@implementation WBCities

@synthesize city, idNumber, size;

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){

    }
    return self;
}

-(int)returnIdNumber{

    return idNumber;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your **`-(void) touchUp:(id)sender`** method with below code

```
-(void) touchUp:(id)sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    WBCities *cityLabel = (WBCities*)tapGesture.view;
    resultNumber = [cityLabel returnIdNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct idNumber you should do something like this:

```
-(void) touchUp:(id)sender
{
    WBCities* city =(WBCities*) sender;

    resultNumber = [city tag];
}
```

The usage of idNumber is  actually redundant you should use the *tag* field instead.

To avoid having to creating a different gesture recognizer for each WBCity i suggest changing WBCities to extend UIControl instead of UILabel and then initialize it like so:

```
    newCity =[[WBCities alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 20, 100, 30)];
    newCity.city = @"CityA";
    newCity.tag = 1111;
    newCity.size = 0;
    [newCity setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [newCity setCity:newCity.city];
    [newCity addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [subView addSubview:newCity];
```

Comment: -(void) touchUp:(id)sender
{
    WBCities *cityLabel = (WBCities*)sender.view
    resultNumber = [newCity returnIdNumber];
}

Comment: That had worked, however it was unable to use the setText method when subclassing from UIControl. I tried to workaround it but was unable to do so, apparently that's available in UILabel. I was able to use this answer in my called method,      UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    WBCities *cityLabel = (WBCities*)tapGesture.view;
    resultNumber = [cityLabel returnIdNumber]; Thanks.

Comment: Use setCity instead of setText.